# Compute Max flow for networks

Tags: algorithm, networking, max, graph-algorithm

can we find an algorithm which computes (in linear-time) the maximum flow for tree-like networks, that is, for networks such that the removal of the sink (and its associated edges) leaves a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just run something like the following:

```
maxf(s) {
  if (s == sink) return s.in_capacity;
  ret = 0;
  foreach(c in children(s)) ret += maxf(c);
  return min(ret, s.in_capacity);
}
```

Use an initial call with s equal to the source (we assume that the source has an in_capacity of infinity).

Comment: The algorithm seems right. It's just "incapacity" that I did not get

Comment: It's the capacity of the incoming edge to that node.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Ford-Fulkerson is O(E*f) where E is the number of edges and f the maximum flow, which would be considered linear if you have a constant upper bound on E or f in your problem.

Comment: The halting problem is O(1) if you have a constant upper bound on the number of states in the Turing Machine. All you need to know is BB(|S|), where |S| is the number of states.